# Converting texture to material

Tags: export

I have a few 3ds models(buildings and floors) and the textures for the models.

I am trying to

- create a map with them on blender and
- after that exporting them as 3ds
- opening them in a viewer 3ds and then
- exporting them as xaml code,

but when I open them in the 3ds viewer, it tells me it cannot find the textures (this could be because i don't know how to use texture and export them that as well, if you could explain that too I would be very grateful).

So what I want to do is turn the texture as part of the material and then when I export I don't need a texture file.

Comment: Could you please add some screenshot describing your issue. You can use the [Edit] link and the add image button?

Comment: there is no picture for me to put i will phrase my Q diffrently

Comment: I have a few 3ds models(buldings and floors) and the textures for the models. I am trying to create a map with them on blender and after that exporting them as 3ds opening them in a viewer 3ds and then exporting them as xaml code. but when i open them in the 3ds veiwer it tell me it can not find the textures (this could be because i dont know how to use texure and export them that well if ou could explain that to i would be very gratefull). so whay i want to do is turn the texture as part of the matiral and then when i export i dont need a texture file.